# Parsing XML data "location" to Google Map

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I would like to parse the "lat" and "lng" tag into the google map.

Currently, I'm retrieving out the data from 
"http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=42t54cX7RbrDFczc&location=singapore" , I'm able to retrieve out the data in a list view with the "title" and "start_time" shown.
Next thing ,that I would like to do is to show the "location" as well.
However, I've met with some problems with it.

I would like the location to appear on the google map (next intent), upon onclick on the title.

I don't know what is wrong with my code,
I couldn't retrieve out the location on the map.

Here is my code:

main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> start_time;
    ArrayList<String> latitude;
    ArrayList<String> longitude;

    ItemAdapter adapter1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        start_time = new ArrayList<String>();
        latitude = new ArrayList<String>();  
        longitude = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=42t54cX7RbrDFczc&location=singapore");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("event");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);      

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();        
                title.add(""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("start_time");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
                start_time.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());          

                NodeList websiteList1 = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("latitude");
                Element websiteElement1 = (Element) websiteList1.item(0);
                websiteList1 = websiteElement1.getChildNodes();
                latitude.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList1.item(0)).getNodeValue());          


                NodeList websiteList2 = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("longitude");
                Element websiteElement2 = (Element) websiteList2.item(0);
                websiteList2 = websiteElement2.getChildNodes();
                longitude.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList2.item(0)).getNodeValue());




            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        adapter1 = new ItemAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }


    class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView title_text;
            public TextView des_text;


        }

        public ItemAdapter(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super();
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
        }

        //@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return title.size();
        }

        //@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mainpage_list,parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
                holder.des_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.des_text);



                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.title_text.setText(""+title.get(position));

            holder.des_text.setText(""+Html.fromHtml(start_time.get(position)));



        return view;
        }
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) 
    {; 

    Intent n = new Intent(MainActivity.this,map.class); 
    n.putExtra("lat",latitude.get(position).toString()); 
    n.putExtra("lng",longitude.get(position).toString());
    startActivity(n); 
    }
}
```

map.java

```
public class map extends  FragmentActivity  {

LatLng storeLocation;
private GoogleMap MAP;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_shown);
    Intent n = getIntent();
    String latitude = n.getStringExtra("lat");
    String longitude= n.getStringExtra("lng");
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    MAP = fm.getMap(); 

    Double lat= Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    Double lng= Double.parseDouble(longitude);


    //MAP = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFM = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
       SupportMapFragment myMAPF = (SupportMapFragment) myFM.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    MAP = myMAPF.getMap();
    MAP.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    MAP.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    storeLocation = new LatLng(lat,
            lng);

   MAP.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(storeLocation).title(
            storeLocation.toString()));



}

private FragmentActivity getActivity() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked latitude and longitude values in main.java after retrieving?

Comment: In the logcat, nothing was shown

Comment: @randomize please log the value of **latitude.get(position).toString()** in the **onListItemClick()** method and check if you are able to get any value or not

Answer (score 1):

You should create a data holder class to hold data for multiple entries of `event` TAG

replace this with your for loop code

```
Vector objVector = new Vector(nodeList.getLength());

     for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
         Node node = nodeList.item(i);      
         Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
         xmldata objXmldata = new xmldata();
         objXmldata.setValue(fstElmnt);
         objVector.addElement(objXmldata);
     }
```

and create a class to hold data of a `event` which is as follows..

```
import java.util.Vector;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class xmldata {

String title = "";
String start_time = "";
String latitude = "";
String longitude = "";

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getStart_time() {
    return start_time;
}

public void setStart_time(String start_time) {
    this.start_time = start_time;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public void setValue(Element fstElmnt) {
    setTitle(fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title").toString());
    setStart_time(fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("start_time").toString());
    setLatitude(fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("latitude").toString());
    setLongitude(fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("longitude").toString());
}

}
```